# Display/hide Highchart content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have a dropdown box, 2 datepicker boxes indicating from & to dates and a button to POST values via AJAX, the results of which are displayed in a graph. When the boxes are inputted and the button is clicked, then a chart should display on the respective `div`. When one of the datepickers is clicked, the `div` should be hidden. When I did that the first time, the behavior seemed normal. But when I did that again, the chart does not appear and this error is shown:

`Uncaught TypeError: O[1].indexOf is not a function`

and this is jsfiddle which is also not get chart on second time

http://jsfiddle.net/t13jymwk/87/

This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var strarr = "[{name:'sfdsdfLi', y:9}, {name:'Kiwsdfi', y:3}, {name:'Mixesdfdnuts', y:1} ,{name:'Oranges', y:6}, {name:'Grapes', y:1}]";
     $(function () {
         $("#search_data").on('click', function () {

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetVo",
             data: JSON.stringify(obj),
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             async: true,
             cache: false,
             success: function (result) {
                 var myData = result.d;
                 console.log(result.d);
                 alert(result.d)
                 if (myData !== null && Object.keys(myData).length !== 0) {
                     strarr = result.d;
                     var myarr = eval(strarr);

                     $("#container").show();

                 }

              else {

                  $("#container").hide();


                  return;
                 }
Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {
                     return {
                         radialGradient: {
                             cx: 0.5,
                             cy: 0.3,
                             r: 0.7
                         },
                         stops: [
                           [0, color],
                           [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
                         ]
                     };
                 });
                 $('#container').highcharts({
                     chart: {
                         events: {
                             load: function (event) {
                                 var total = 0;
                                 for (var i = 0, len = this.series[0].yData.length; i < len; i++) {
                                     total += this.series[0].yData[i];
                                 }
                                 var text = this.renderer.text(
                                   'Total: ' + total,
                                   this.plotLeft,
                                   this.plotTop - 20
                               ).attr({
                                   zIndex: 5
                               }).add()
                             }
                         },                 
                         plotBackgroundColor: null,
                         plotBorderWidth: 1,
                         plotShadow: false,
                         width: 500,
                         height: 300,
                         type: 'pie'                         
                     },
                     title: {
                         text: ' Region: '  + reg
                     },
                     subtitle: {
    text: '<br> From Date:' + obj.fromdate + '<br> To Date:' + obj.todate
                     },
                     tooltip: {
                         pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y}'
                     },
                     plotOptions: {
                         pie: {
                             allowPointSelect: true,
                             cursor: 'pointer',
                             dataLabels: {
                                 enabled: true,
                                 format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y}',
                             },
                             showInLegend: true
                         }
                     },
                     series: [{
                         name: 'Delivered amount',
                         data: myarr
                     }]
                 });   },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('no data');
            }
        });

<script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
             var currentMonth = (new Date).getMonth();
             var currentDay = (new Date).getDate();
             $('#fromdate').datepicker({
                 showSecond: false,
                 timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                 minDate: new Date((currentYear - 2), 12, 1),
                 dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                 maxDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay),
                 onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                     var startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                     $('#todate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', startDate);
                     $('#todate').datepicker('setDate', startDate);
                     var enddate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                     enddate.setDate(enddate.getDate() + 60); 
                     $('#todate').datetimepicker('option', 'maxDate', enddate);
                 }
             });

             $('#todate').datepicker({
                 showSecond: false,
                 timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                 minDate: new Date((currentYear - 2), 12, 1),
                 minDate: 0,
                 dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                 maxDate: '+30',     
             });

             $('#fromdate').on('click', function () {

                 $('#container').hide();

             $('#todate').on('click', function () {

                 $('#container').hide();

             });
         });
      </script>
```

HTML:

```
      <div id="container" class="container1">

      </div>

 <asp:DropDownList ID="regiondrop" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="regiondrop_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>  

      <span>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="From Date"></asp:Label>

    <input  ID="fromdate"   value="dd/mm/yyyy" runat="server" clientidmode="static" />

   </span>
     <span>
     <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="To Date"></asp:Label>

     <input  ID="todate"   value="dd/mm/yyyy" runat="server" clientidmode="static" />
   </span>

<input type="button" id="search_data"    class="sear_btn"  value="Search Data" />
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. So, the jsfiddle shows exactly how it is supposed to work correctly? If so, this seems odd, because changing the dates in the jsfiddle with the date picker does not change the chart at all. Thanks for further info.

Comment: i only paste html datepicker.. these dates not work according to the chart.. . but in my code chart display according to the date

Comment: Your code does not seem reproducible to me. E.g. you are referring to DOM nodes such as #seach_data which I cannot find in your code. Plus, you have ajax requests in there which I cannot reproduce.

Comment: @nilsole check update. and yes i have a getvo static function which i call in ajax

Comment: @nilsole  i remove parameters and date-time picker then when i simple display chart on button click then same problem happen .. first time this is display then when i click again on button then this show error

Comment: @nilsole check updated js fiddle i post js fiddle which i use in my code and also in js fiddle second time chart not display chart

Answer (score 0):

ok i solve this i paste this part  before this line and this work for me

```
 $("#search_data").on('click', function () {

Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {
                     return {
                         radialGradient: {
                             cx: 0.5,
                             cy: 0.3,
                             r: 0.7
                         },
                         stops: [
                           [0, color],
                           [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
                         ]
                     };
                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `chart.update()` function that comes with Highcharts.

http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/Chart.update

- Define a new var for your chart so you can work with it later.
- Save new Highcharts instance in that variable.
- update the instance whenever you like.

My code for that purpose, [try it in jsfiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/jbv011pf/2/)

```
var chart, chartObj, strArray = [
  ['sfdsdfLi', 9],
  ['Kiwsdfi', 3],
  ['Mixesdfd nuts', 1],
  ['Oranges', 6],
  ['Grapes (bunch)', 1]
];

$(function() {
  $('[ID*=search_data]').on('click', function() {
    Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
      return {
        radialGradient: {
          cx: 0.5,
          cy: 0.3,
          r: 0.7
        },
        stops: [
          [0, color],
          [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
        ]
      };
    });

    chartObj = {
      chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
      },
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          allowPointSelect: true,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
            style: {
              color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
            },
            connectorColor: 'silver'
          }
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        data: [{
          name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
          y: 56.33
        }, {
          name: 'Chrome',
          y: 24.03,
          sliced: true,
          selected: true
        }, {
          name: 'Firefox',
          y: 10.38
        }, {
          name: 'Safari',
          y: 4.77
        }, {
          name: 'Opera',
          y: 0.91
        }, {
          name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
          y: 0.2
        }]
      }]
    };

    if (typeof chart !== "undefined") {
      console.log("updating!");
      chart.update(chartObj);
    } else {
      console.log("creating!");
      chart = Highcharts.chart('container', chartObj);
    }
  });
});
/*,
    error: function (Result) {
      alert("Error");
    }
  });
}*/
```